# Create own version of Optional

Tags: python, mypy, python-typing

I have something like this in my code:

```py
Undefined = Literal['__undefined_attr__']
undefined: Undefined = '__undefined_attr__'

def funkc(
    foo: Union[str, Undefined] = undefined,
    bar: Union[int, Undefined] = undefined,
    baz: Union[str, Undefined] = undefined,
    boo: Union[float, Undefined] = undefined,
    # ... lots more args like that with many different types
):
    if foo is not undefined:
        ...
    if bar is not undefined:
        ...
    ...  # etc.
```

Now, if I could use None as the default value, this would all get much simpler, like:

```py
def funkc(
    foo: Optional[str] = None,
    bar: Optional[int] = None,
    baz: Optional[str] = None,
    boo: Optional[float] = None,
    # ... lots more args like that with many different types
):
    if foo is not None:
        ...
    if bar is not None:
        ...
    ...  # etc.
```

So I was thinking I could create my own type shortcut, which could be used like:

```py
def funkc(
    foo: OptionallyDefined[str] = undefined,
    bar: OptionallyDefined[int] = undefined,
    baz: OptionallyDefined[str] = undefined,
    boo: OptionallyDefined[float] = undefined,
    # ... lots more args like that with many different types
):
    if foo is not undefined:
        ...
    if bar is not undefined:
        ...
    ...  # etc.
```

But actually creating this `OptionalylDefined` thing is escaping me. Is this possible with mypy?

---

**Solution:**

Thanks to [user2357112 supports Monica's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59303785/236195), this it what I'm using in the end:

```py
class Undefined:
    instance = None

    def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs) -> "Undefined":
        """Singleton, just in case..."""
        if not cls.instance:
            cls.instance = super().__new__(cls, *args, **kwargs)  # type: ignore
        return cls.instance


undefined = Undefined()
ArgType = TypeVar("ArgType")
OptionallyDefined = Union[ArgType, Undefined]


def funkc(...):
    if foo is not undefined:
        ...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have mypy here, so I can't test this, but the following should work. (Make sure you test it with mypy, not just by running it):

```
T = typing.TypeVar('T')

OptionallyDefined = typing.Union[T, Undefined]

def funkc(
    foo: OptionallyDefined[str] = undefined,
    ...
):
    ...
```

Your own TypeVar attempt failed because you simultaneously changed the definition of `undefined` in a way that's incompatible with `typing.Literal`.

---

As an aside, that way of defining and using `undefined` isn't safe. MyPy will consider any `'__undefined_attr__'` string to be a valid value of type `Undefined`, but your `is` comparisons will reject some strings and allow others, depending on implementation details and where any particular string came from. I would write a class and use an instance of the class for `undefined`, instead of using a string and `typing.Literal`.

Comment: Ah, yes, that `is` is actually a leftover when I was using `undefined = object()`. However `Literal` only works on strings, ints and such, but not on objects :( Thanks for the heads up!